# onclick funtion not working beacause it not in the main retun statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to make history by pushing on button click

**onclick function of the li is not working**

as u can see in the code `<SuggestionsList/>` is in the last return statement its funtions are rendered in   `const SuggestionsList = (props) => {`   . The onclick funtion is comimg inside the  `const SuggestionsList` funtion, this is making the onclick funtion not working

```
 const history = useHistory();
 function finddoctor(e) {
    console.log(e);
    history.push(`/detiled/${e} `);
  }
```

```
 
  const onChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setInputValue(value);
    setShowResults(false);

    

    const filteredSuggestions = suggestions.filter(
      (suggestion) =>
        suggestion.firstname
          .toString()
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(value.toLowerCase()) ||
        suggestion.id.toString().toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
    );

  

    setFilteredSuggestions(filteredSuggestions);
    setDisplaySuggestions(true);
  };

  const onSelectSuggestion = (index) => {
    setSelectedSuggestion(index);
    setInputValue(filteredSuggestions[index]);
    setFilteredSuggestions([]);
    setDisplaySuggestions(false);
  };

  const SuggestionsList = (props) => {
  const {
      suggestions,
      inputValue,

      onSelectSuggestion,
      displaySuggestions,
      selectedSuggestion,
    } = props;

    if (inputValue && displaySuggestions) {
      if (suggestions.length > 0) {
        return (
          <ul className="suggestions-list" style={styles.ulstyle}>
            {suggestions.map((suggestion, index) => {
    
              const isSelected = selectedSuggestion === index;
              const classname = `suggestion ${isSelected ? "selected" : ""}`;
              return (
                <>
              
                  <li
                    style={styles.listyle}
                     onClick={() => finddoctor(suggestion.id)}
                    key={index}
                    className={classname}
                  >
                    {suggestion.firstname}
                  </li>
                </>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        );
      } else {
        return <div>No suggestions available...</div>;
      }
    }
    return <></>;
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("admin-panel/all-doctors-list/")
      .then((res) => {
        const data = res.data;
      setShowSerch(data);

      });
  
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="note-container" style={styles.card}>
        <div style={styles.inner}>
          <p style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>Search Doctors</p>
          <form className="search-form" style={{}}>
            {showResults ? (
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                style={{ marginRight: "-23px" }}
                icon={faSearch}
              />
            ) : null}
            <input
              onChange={onChange}
              value={inputValue}
              style={styles.input}
              type="Search"
            />

            <SuggestionsList
              inputValue={inputValue}
              selectedSuggestion={selectedSuggestion}
              onSelectSuggestion={onSelectSuggestion}
              displaySuggestions={displaySuggestions}
              suggestions={filteredSuggestions}
            />
          </form>
         
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Given `useHistory` is a hook, it (and subsequently `finddoctor`) should be within your functional component

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-ritchie-x2tcr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: i created this sandbox and its woeking but its not wroking in my project

Comment: Along with what Phil mentions, the component using `history` needs to be rendered within a `Router` component. The code in your linked sandbox doesn't appear to run and reproduce your issue; you've commented so much of it out it renders only a horizontal line. I'm not sure what we can do with it in its current state.

Comment: the horizontal line is a input fild u can type name there and if name exixt in api it will show in the li tag and its clickable aslo when clicked the id is displayed in console

Comment: clcik on the horizontal line u can see in animating to input fild

Comment: i copyed the exact code into my local project but the li does not become clikable and its not consoleloging the id when i click

Comment: i know it doent  reproduce the issue and thats what i am rying to solve it works in codesandbox but it doenot work in my local project;

Comment: Ok, I see, the line is a text input. I don't know what your sandbox reproduces or what you say is working there. As I mentioned previously, you've commented out a lot of the code, specifically the `history.push(\`/detiled/${e}\`);` code you mention isn't working, for example. It's not our job to debug/get your sandbox into a running/reproducible state. If you uncommented the `history.push` line, what are you expecting? What exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see you've simply neglected to provide a routing context to your application. When uncommenting the `` history.push(`/detiled/${e}`); `` line in `Searchclients` and attempting some search/navigation I see the following error:

> ```
> TypeError
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
> ```

Assuming this is the same error you have then the solution is simple: wrap the app in a `Router` component in order to provide a routing context.

Example:

App.js

```
const finddoctor = (e) => {
  console.log(e);
  history.push(`/detiled/${e}`);
};
```

index.js:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

[image: Edit onclick-funtion-not-working-beacause-it-not-in-the-main-retun-statement]